# Managing one to many entities in sonata admin bundle

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

Imagine you are developing a website using symfony2 and it's admin panel using Sonata Admin Bundle and of course imagine you have a class named Product which owns some Images. Image is also a class and you have set in  Product a one to many relation-ship to Image class. So every image is owned by a product, so you want to manage Image Admin inside Product Admin classes. 
So there are some problems you should to face with them. Would you please to tell how?
1. When you delete a product object, all images related to that product be deleted.
2. When you are in show product page or add new product page the picture of all of images display on page. 
(Is there any solution without using sonata media bundle too?)
Thanks

I handle Image upload with Document class:

```html
FstQst\WebBundle\Entity\Document:
    type: entity
    table: null
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO

    fields:
        updated:        # changed when files are uploaded, to force preUpdate and postUpdate to fire
            type:         datetime
            nullable:     true

        format:
            type: string
            length: 25
            nullable: true


    lifecycleCallbacks:
        prePersist:   [ preUpload ]
        preUpdate:    [ preUpload ]
        postPersist:  [upload]
        postUpdate:   [upload]
        postRemove: [removeUpload]
```

I have another class using Document for adding some features to image:

```html
FstQst\WebBundle\Entity\Post:
    type: entity
    table: null
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO

    fields:
        title:
            type: string
            length: 100
            nullable: true


    oneToOne:
        document:
            targetEntity: Document
            joinColumn:
                name: document_id
                referencedColumnName: id
            orphanRemoval: true

    manyToOne:
        site:
            targetEntity: VisitablePoint
            inversedBy: posts
            joinColumn:
                name: vPoint_id
                referencedColumnName: id

    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

And a class named VisitablePoint, which uses Post class:

```html
FstQst\WebBundle\Entity\VisitablePoint:
    type: entity
    table: visitablePoint
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO


    oneToMany:
        posts:
            targetEntity: Post
            mappedBy: site
            orphanRemoval: true

    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

I changed my classes names from Post to Image and from VisitablePoint to Product at my old post. Now I want when I go to VisitablePoint admin/show page I see pictures of Post object instead of their title. And of course in admin/edit page too.

And these are Admin Classes:

```html
<?php

namespace FstQst\WebBundle\Admin;

use FstQst\WebBundle\Entity\Document;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Show\ShowMapper;

class DocumentAdmin extends Admin
{
    /**
     * @param ListMapper $listMapper
     */
    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper
            ->add('id')
            ->add('updated')
            ->add('_action', 'actions', array(
                'actions' => array(
                    'show' => array(),
                    'edit' => array(),
                    'delete' => array(),
                )
            ))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param FormMapper $formMapper
     */
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {

        $formMapper
            ->add('file', 'file', $this->getFieldOptionForImagePreview())
        ;
    }


    /**
     * @param ShowMapper $showMapper
     */
    protected function configureShowFields(ShowMapper $showMapper)
    {
        $showMapper
            ->add('id')
            ->add('updated')
            ->add('format')
        ;
    }

    public function prePersist($image) {
        $this->manageFileUpload($image);
    }

    public function preUpdate($image) {
        $this->manageFileUpload($image);
    }

    protected function manageFileUpload(Document $image) {
        if ($image->getFile()) {
            $image->refreshUpdated();
        }
    }

    protected function getFieldOptionForImagePreview($maxSize = 200){
        if($this->hasParentFieldDescription()) { // this Admin is embedded
            // $getter will be something like 'getlogoImage'
            $getter = 'get' . $this->getParentFieldDescription()->getFieldName();

            // get hold of the parent object
            $parent = $this->getParentFieldDescription()->getAdmin()->getSubject();
            if ($parent) {
                $document = $parent->$getter();
            } else {
                $document = null;
            }
        } else {
            $document = $this->getSubject();
        }

        // use $fileFieldOptions so we can add other options to the field
        $fileFieldOptions = array('required' => false);
        if ($document && ($webPath = $document->getWebPath())) {
            // get the container so the full path to the image can be set
            $container = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer();
            $fullPath = $container->get('request')->getBasePath().'/'.$webPath;
            //$fileFieldOptions['help'] = '<img src="/uploads/documents/10.png" class="admin-preview" style="max-height: 200px; max-width: 200px"/>';
            $fileFieldOptions['help'] = <<<START
<img src="$fullPath" style="max-height: {$maxSize}px; max-width: {$maxSize}px"/>
START;
        }

        return $fileFieldOptions;
    }

}
```

```html
<?php

namespace FstQst\WebBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Show\ShowMapper;

class VisitablePointAdmin extends Admin
{

    /**
     * @param FormMapper $formMapper
     */
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->add('posts', 'sonata_type_model', array('multiple' => true, 'property' => 'title', 'label' => 'Image', 'required' => false))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param ShowMapper $showMapper
     */
    protected function configureShowFields(ShowMapper $showMapper)
    {
        $showMapper
             ->add('posts', 'sonata_type_collection', ['label' => 'Images',
                'required' => false, 'cascade_validation' => true,
                'by_reference' => false], ['edit' => 'inline', 'inline' => 'table'])
            ->end()
        ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

## The One to Many relation

**1. When you delete a product object, all images related to that product be deleted.**

You can easily manage this kind of deletion with the orphanRemoval="true"

```
<?php
class Product{
    [...]
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Event", mappedBy="day", orphanRemoval="true", cascade={"all"})
     */
    private $images;
    [...]
}
```

in yml, the configuration looks like:

```
oneToMany:
  images:
    targetEntity: Image
    orphanRemoval: true
    mappedBy: product
```

**2. When you are in show product page or add new product page the picture of all of images display on page.**

You have to use a sonata_type_collection in your configureFormFields or your configureShowFields method of your ProductAdmin class:

```
<?php
class ProductAdmin{
    [...]
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper) {
        $formMapper
            ->with('tab_images')
                ->add('images', 'sonata_type_collection', array(
                    'required' => false,
                    'cascade_validation' => true,
                    'by_reference' => false,
                ), array(
                    'edit' => 'inline',
                    'inline' => 'table',
                ))
            ->end()
        ;
    }
    [...]
}
```

Then provide a ImageAdmin with all you need to upload files.
You might have to change settings because i took it from a personal project and i don't know if it's totally adapted to your needs.

## Show images in Sonata

first configure your ImageAdmin as follow:

```
class ImageAdmin extends Admin
{
    [...]
    protected function configureShowFields(ShowMapper $showMapper) {
        $showMapper
            ->add('myImageAttr', 'image', array(
                'prefix' => '/',
            ))
        ;
    }
    [...]
    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper) {
        $listMapper
            ->add('myImageAttr', 'image', array(
                'prefix' => '/',
                'width' => 100
            ))
        ;
    }
}
```

then create template for your list_image and you show_image types:

Resources/views/CRUD/show_image.html.twig

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show_field.html.twig' %}
{% block field %}
    {% if value %}
        <img src="{% if field_description.options.prefix %}{{ field_description.options.prefix }}{% endif %}{{ value }}" />
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Resources/views/CRUD/list_image.html.twig

```
{% extends admin.getTemplate('base_list_field') %}

{% block field%}
{% spaceless %}
    {% set width = field_description.options.width is defined ? field_description.options.width : 50 %}
    {% set height = field_description.options.height is defined ? field_description.options.height : 50 %}
    {% if value %}
        <img src="{% if field_description.options.prefix is defined %}{{ field_description.options.prefix }}{% endif %}{{ value }}" 
            style="max-width:{{ width }}px; max-height:{{ height }}px;" />
    {% else %}
        <div class="no-image" style="width:{{ width }}px; height:{{ height }}px;"></div>
    {% endif %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

finally, add this configuration into your app/config/config.yml

```
sonata_doctrine_orm_admin:
  templates:
    types:
      show:
        image: YourBundle:CRUD:show_image.html.twig
      list:
        image: YourBundle:CRUD:list_image.html.twig
```

(http://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/master/doc/reference/templates.html)

Comment: Would you please to write orm options in yml

Comment: My second problem is that in product show page it shows me the name of image instead of its preview. Of course it's because when I override the __toString function in Image class I returned the title of image. I am trying to return an html like <img src='...'> for previewing but it does not work

Comment: Post the Twig code that isn't working.  For your other one, just add `orphanRemoval: true` under the entity under the `oneToMany` section of your .yml

Comment: i updated the answer for the orm option in yml (same as @JasonRoman solution), and i'll update the answer for your second question

Comment: Thanks my friend. I solved my problem with orphamRemove, but not still with showing images. I updated my post and added some information containing yml files.

Comment: Till now my friends you ashamed me from your careful answers. Thanks you anyway.

Comment: I added Admin classes too.