# Show 2 layer collections type in sonata admin bundle

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata, symfony-2.8

I work with symfony 2.8 and SonataAdminBundle : I have 3 Entities: ( Commande, LigneCommande and Produits) 
Commande : can have Many 'LigneCommande' ,
LigneCommande : can have only One 'Produit'
I create a CommandAdmin class to display all 'commandes' and I like to display all 'Produits' inside a 'commande' (Command line Product's in this command)

**CommandeAdmin**

```
 protected function configureShowFields(ShowMapper $showMapper)
  {
    $showMapper
        ->add('id')
        ->add('dateCreation')
        ->add('client.nom')

        ->add('operation.nom')
        ->add('correspondant.nom')
        ->add('correspondant.adresse', null, array(
            'label' => 'Adresse de livraison')
        )
      ;
      $lcs=$this->getSubject()->getLignesCommande();
      foreach ($lcs as $lc) {
          $n=$lc->getProduit()->getNom();
          $q=(string)($lc->getQte());
          // $this->configureListFields($listMapper);
          $showMapper 
               ->with($n)
                  ->add($n)
                  ->add($q)
               ->end()
                ;
        }
```

what should I do to access to product's qte ?? 
I have this error :

```
Duplicate field name "3" in show mapper. Names should be unique.
```

thank you all

Comment: For one to many relations in Sonata Admin you have `collection_types` https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/form_types.html#sonata-type-collection. This can also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27667905/managing-one-to-many-entities-in-sonata-admin-bundle

Comment: My problem is not for the relation between the entities, but that is for the showMapper

Comment: Did you fix it?